# gcloud command for bulk metadata update

Tags: bash, gcloud, xargs

I am trying to craft a gcloud command that does a bulk metadata update on compute engine instances.

Normally I could just pipe `gcloud compute instances list` to `xargs gcloud compute instances add-metadata`. However, this is thwarted because for some inexplicable reason, `add-metadata` needs *both* an instance name, *and* a zone, even though compute instance names appear to be globally unique. So now I'm forced to try to shuttle both pieces of data  (both name and zone) to the add-metadata command. If I don't provide both, I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.add-metadata) Underspecified resource [worker-1]. Specify the [--zone] flag.
```

I'm about ready to give up on the bash/xargs incantation and switch to python but I thought I'd check here first.

I have this command:

```
gcloud compute instances list \
        --filter="name~'worker' AND zone~'us-central1'" \
        --format 'value(name,zone)'
```

which returns something like:

```
worker-1    us-central1-c
worker-2    us-central1-c
worker-3    us-central1-c
worker-4    us-central1-c
```

I then need to pipe these into a command like:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata --zone=[zone goes here] --metadata myvalue=true [instance name goes here]
```

But this is proving tricky/annoying using xargs alone. Is there a better or simpler way to accomplish what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipe it to while read sequence:

```
gcloud compute instances list \
       --filter="name~'worker' AND zone~'us-central1'" \
       --format 'value(name,zone)' | \
while read instance zone; do
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata \
    --zone=$zone --metadata myvalue=true $instance
done
```

Comment: Nice, this is much more readable than the unholy xargs incantation I was crafting

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap a `sh` "in the middle" to help with positional arguments.
In your case you can run below CLI, noting that it'll `echo` the `gcloud` commands that it would run, then once comfortable with the resulting set of commands, either remove the `echo` there, or run the whole command `|sh -x` :

```shell
gcloud compute instances list \
        --filter="name~'worker' AND zone~'us-central1'" \
        --format 'value(name,zone)' |\
xargs -n2 sh -c \
'echo gcloud compute instances add-metadata --zone="$2" --metadata myvalue=true "$1"' --
```

The trick here is this CLI arrangement: `xargs -n2 sh -c '... $1 ... $2' --`

- `-n2` to let `xargs` pass in args in groups of two
- `sh -c '... $1 ... $2' --` as a mini scriptlet